# Correlated NOT EXISTS error: The multi-part identifier "xxx" could not be bound

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2

```
update IQAlarm
set IQAD=GETDATE(),AD=AD+1
where exists (select CPC from Inquiry where Inquiry.IQST='ooo' 
  and DATEDIFF(DAY,GETDATE(),Inquiry.QDL)<=3 and Inquiry.CPC = IQAlarm.CPC);

insert into IQAlarm (CPC)  
select CPC from Inquiry   
where not exists (select CPC from Inquiry where Inquiry.IQST='ooo' 
and DATEDIFF(DAY,GETDATE(),Inquiry.QDL)<=3 and Inquiry.CPC = **IQAlarm.CPC**);
```

The update works fine, but the insert yields this error:

> The multi-part identifier "IQAlarm.CPC" could not be bound.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first update should have a `FROM` clause to support correlation (but I'm not shocked it works without one - it's just not how I'd write it).

```
UPDATE IQAlarm
set IQAD=GETDATE(),AD=AD+1
FROM IQAlarm -- <----- you need this
where exists (select CPC from Inquiry 
  where Inquiry.IQST='ooo' and DATEDIFF(DAY,GETDATE(),Inquiry.QDL)<=3 
  and Inquiry.CPC = IQAlarm.CPC);
```

And I think your second is all messed up. Perhaps this is what you meant:

```
insert into IQAlarm (CPC)
  select CPC from Inquiry
  where IQST='ooo' 
   and DATEDIFF(DAY,GETDATE(),Inquiry.QDL)<=3 
  and not exists (SELECT 1 FROM IQAlarm WHERE CPC = Inquiry.CPC);
```

Comment: Thanks for answering.
I tried the update query whit your modification, but it didn't work. Update query doesn't have "from" in it. Reference page here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187348.aspx
And the insert query works very well!!
I understand what's wrong with my query string now.
One more step to be a pro just like you!

Comment: @Ghashgul The link you sent is to `UPDATE STATISTICS` not `UPDATE`, and can you explain what "didn't work" means?

Comment: It works! Didn't know why i got error from last time. False alarm.  Preciate for your kindly help. But it still works without "from". So weird.